# Default username and password for Oracle database

Tags: database, oracle

I forgot to feed sys, system and hr password while Oracle DB installation and hit OK but now for SQ*Plus it needs those credentials for login in command prompt.How to get default user name and password?

Comment: You don't need reinstalling. If you have access to the terminal, you can log in as OS user which is member of `dba` group, and then log in as privileged user with SQL*Plus `sqlplus / as sysdba`. Once you logged in, you can alter any account you want.

Comment: @jani yes that is possible with 11g but i am afraid the case is different with 12c.As Lalit mentioned.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can simply login as :

```
sqlplus / as sysdba
```

Then give password to the respective users :

```
ALTER USER <username> IDENTIFIED BY <password>;
```

You can do that for all the three users.

I hope you are not on 12c. Else, you need to mention which CONTAINER are you working with. For example, if you are working on pluggable database, let's say PDBORCL, you need to do following steps :

1. `connect / as sysdba;`
2. alter session to set the container of which the respective users are a part of.

   `alter session set container=PDBORCL;`
3. Then follow the same steps to change the passwords for the users.

Comment: Yes, I was using 12c unfortunately. The support for 12c is less.Got connected with the help of your three steps.Also, 12c has few more problems like the deinstall feature for broken installed software pieces is available for 11g but not 12c.

Comment: Well, I believe you are very fortunate to work on 12c. It has lot of new features and really exciting. All you need is to know how to do what :-)

Answer (score 1):

CHANGE_ON_INSTALL is default password for sys and system.

You can directly login to database as sysdba from host machine and using installation user of oracle and execute below command to change system or sys password.

sqlplus "/as sysdba"

alter user sys identified by passwd;

Alternatively you can create password file to from host server

go to directory 
$ORACLE_HOME\database (windows)
$ORACLE_HOME\dbs (unix\linux)

and execute

orapwd password=password file=orapwSID force=y entries=5

and login to database .