# Default username and password for SQL*Plus in Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: oracle, ubuntu-14.04, sqlplus

I followed the instructions mentioned to install SQL*Plus from [Oracle Instant Client](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Oracle%20Instant%20Client) and [How to Install SQLPlus](https://askubuntu.com/questions/159939/how-to-install-sqlplus).

SQL*Plus is successfully installed on my system but I cannot login and use it. There is a similar question [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/585520/how-to-run-sql-plus-in-ubuntu-14-04) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25741027/default-username-and-password-for-oracle-database), but it is does not solve my problem.

On googling, most sources said that we enter a password upon installation, but I was neither prompted nor displayed any password. (I can attach terminal screen shots if it is required)

Is there any way I can login and start using SQL*Plus? Is there any default username or password?

I am stuck here: `sqlplus username/password@//dbhost:1521/SID`

I need a valid username and password. `scott/tiger` was of no help.

`sqlplus / as sysdba` gives this -> `ERROR: ORA-12162: TNS:net service name is incorrectly specified` and prompts me to enter username and password which I don't have.

I originally asked this question on [AskUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/658070/default-username-and-password-for-sqlplus-in-ubuntu-14-04) feeling its more appropriate there. If this question does not belong here, please comment and I will remove it.

**EDIT:**

I executed these statements after reading from [here](http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_ora_12162_tns_net_service_name.htm):

`ORACLE_HOME=/u01/oracle; export ORACLE_HOME`

`ORACLE_SID=asdb; export ORACLE_SID`

Now, On executing `sqlplus / as sysdba` I get the error message
`ERROR: ORA-12545: Connect failed because target host or object does not exist`

On executing `sqlplus64 scott/tiger@//dbhost:1521/SID` I get the error message
`ERROR: ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified`

Comment: Is that the only error message you get: `ORA 12162`? It really helps to provide error messages rather than 'cannot login' and 'stuck' and 'was of no help'. If you're only getting ORA 12162 then it is likely to be a completely different issue - it can't even find the listener which it needs to do before even checking your login.

Comment: When you issue `sqlplus / as sysdba` sqlplus looks for ORACLE_SID variable, which is not set and this is what ORA-12162 is about. You can get the same error if you would specify the wrong service name in `sqlplus username/password@//dbhost:1521/service_name`. Look into the ORA-12162 description using `oerr ora 12162`.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid Yes, I am only getting the Error message `ORA 12162`. What should I do to get rid of this error? Sorry, I thought posting all details may help in better understanding. Will keep that in mind next time.

Comment: You didn't post all details..... For example you need to change " but I cannot login and use it." to "when I login by doing _this_, then i get _this_ error message"

Comment: Please post the full syntax you are using for `scott/tiger` example, and post the exact error you get back

Comment: All of the links you mention in your original post are only for installing the Oracle **client**. If that is the case you do not have an Oracle server to connect to.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid Updated post to reflect the error on using `scott/tiger`. How to connect to an Oracle server?

Comment: An Oracle server has to be installed... somewhere. If you didn't install it then you need to. Usually someone else has installed it (i.e. an Oracle DBA) and they just give you the various parameters (SID, username, password)

Comment: No DBA is there to assign me those parameters. I am installing and using it on my personal laptop for personal use. How should I install oracle server?

Comment: @stee1rat has provided a link - follow that

Answer (score 0):

It does not have anything to do with Ubuntu. When you enter `sqlplus / as sysdba` sqlplus tries to connect to the local database, which sid and oracle home should be specified by the environment variables `ORACLE_SID` and `ORACLE_HOME`. You, obviously, have not defined these variables.

All you need is to get the username, password, host name, where your database is located, port for the listener (the default port is 1521) and the Oracle SID. Then connect with `sqlplus username/password@//dbhost:1521/SID`. If you know the password for SYS user and have orapwSID file in the $ORACLE_HOME/dbs directory on the server side, you can connect with sys with the following command: `sqlplus sys/password@//dbhost:1521/SID as sysdba`.

Comment: The OP says he does not know _any_ passwords

Comment: Then he can not connect to a database rather then from the local server with `sqlplus / as sysdba` and, judging by his post, he only installed instant client, so he HAS to know the passwords. This is what I described.

Comment: @stee1rat Yup, exactly what you are saying. For any wrong service name I get the same error message. How should I go about in removing these error messages? Sorry if the question is too easy or trivial, I am just a beginner.

Comment: Yes.. it looks like he only installed the client.... for that he does not need to know any Oracle passwords.

Comment: He does not need to know any passwords to install the Oracle client software - that is for sure. But he needs to know the password and the connection parameters of the database he wants to connect to remotely. @sanchitkum do you know the server, port, service_name/sid along with username/password for the database?

Comment: @stee1rat No I don't know any of those details. I was installing it to practice SQL*Plus on my laptop. So no DBA gave me any of those details. I think I need to install Oracle server? If that is the case, please tell me how should I install Oracle server on my laptop?

Comment: Yeah, sqlplus is just a client software to connect to the Oracle database. You should install Oracle RDBMS and create a database using it. Just follow the [Oracle documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LADBI/inst_task.htm#BABBBHJH). I also think that there should be Oracle Database XE in Ubuntu repositories. At least it once was.

Answer (score 0):

moving everything into `instant_client_11_*` directory worked for me.